# Java GeoTools search for features in range with WGS84 input and "EPSG:3857" shape

Tags: java, geotools

I have a shape file re-projected in "EPSG:3857" and I'm trying to find features within a certain range expressed in meters from a point I get in lat/lon (WGS84).

Using dwithin i need to pass a range higher than the real distance so getting that this happens because of an issue with "EPSG:3857" and dwithin, I switched to a buffered geometry, look for features at certain distance from my point. This is my code:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem WGS84 =  CRS.decode("EPSG:4326",true);   //org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84 Google Earth;
CoordinateReferenceSystem EPSG3857 = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857",true); //WGS84 Pseudo-Mercator: shape reprojected CRS------------- String code = "AUTO:42001," + x + "," + y;
MathTransform transformToEPSG3857 = CRS.findMathTransform(WGS84, EPSG3857, false);

GeometryFactory geometryFactory2 = new GeometryFactory();
Geometry pointSource = geometryFactory.createPoint(coordinateSource); // coordinateSource is lat=41.942667 lon=12.462218
Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform(pointSource, transformToEPSG3857);

Geometry buffer = targetGeometry.buffer(distance);
buffer.setSRID(3857);
Filter pointInPolygon = filterFactory.contains(filterFactory.property("the_geom"), filterFactory.literal(buffer));
SimpleFeatureCollection features = shapeFileNamedCache.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(pointInPolygon);
System.out.println("Features: " + features.size() + " at distance in meters: " + distance);
```

I'm not getting why this code does not filter out any feature, while I know there are.

Any advice will help me.

Stefano.

Buffer contains this:

```
POLYGON ((1387457.7619147683 5152395.103885399, 1387454.4954124368 5152361.9385306565, 1387444.8214352953 5152330.047701897, 1387429.1117488598 5152300.6569457855, 1387407.97006757 5152274.895732597, 1387382.2088543817 5152253.754051308, 1387352.8180982703 5152238.044364872, 1387320.927269511 5152228.37038773, 1387287.7619147683 5152225.103885399, 1387254.5965600256 5152228.37038773, 1387222.7057312662 5152238.044364872, 1387193.3149751548 5152253.754051308, 1387167.5537619665 5152274.895732597, 1387146.4120806768 5152300.6569457855, 1387130.7023942412 5152330.047701897, 1387121.0284170997 5152361.9385306565, 1387117.7619147683 5152395.103885399, 1387121.0284170997 5152428.269240142, 1387130.7023942412 5152460.160068901, 1387146.4120806768 5152489.550825013, 1387167.5537619665 5152515.312038201, 1387193.3149751548 5152536.45371949, 1387222.7057312662 5152552.163405926, 1387254.5965600256 5152561.837383068, 1387287.7619147683 5152565.103885399, 1387320.927269511 5152561.837383068, 1387352.8180982703 5152552.163405926, 1387382.2088543817 5152536.45371949, 1387407.97006757 5152515.312038201, 1387429.1117488598 5152489.550825013, 1387444.8214352953 5152460.160068901, 1387454.4954124368 5152428.269240142, 1387457.7619147683 5152395.103885399))
```

in meters I pass 170 but properties are closer. Shape file is reprojected via QGIS into WGS84 Pseudo-mercator. The strange is that if i use the original file with CRS being ED_1950_UTM_Zone_33N, the distance is correct and features are closer as expected (found at 123 meters instead of 167).

Comment: what is buffer equal to, please add the WKT to the question. How are you reprojecting the shapefile?

Comment: Please edit the question

Comment: Question edited. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

After moving to the same shape file BUT NOT reprojected, using as a consequence

```
sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:23033", true);
```

Because of the different CRS, things chaged.

Before: perfect positioning of point on map, 50 meters difference in computing distances

Now: points positioning and distance are all with an error of about 3 meters.

No idea at all why this is happening (still looking) but at least error has decreased.

Note: to do tests I'm using Google Earth with a KLM file coming from an export made via a GIS.